# receiving warning of uninitialized local variable

Tags: c++

I am writing a program and I am trying to overload to << operator. When I debug my code, i receive an error saying that p is not initialized. I feel as if i am initializing p in the for statement, but i guess i am not. cannot seem to figure out how i would initialize p. this is the code where i am receiving the error message. anyy suggestions?

```
ostream &operator <<( ostream &out, const LList & llist )
{

for( LList *p = p; p != 0; p = p -> next )
    out << p;

return out;
}
```

Comment: `p` is initializing itself which is uninitialized. Is there a member `p` of `LList` ?

Answer (score 6):

You are initialising p with itself which does nothing, perhaps you mean to point it at the llist parameter thats being passed to the function?

Maybe something like this?

```
for( const LList *p = &llist; p != 0; p = p -> next )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ostream &operator <<( ostream &out, const LList & llist )
 {
      for(const LList *p = llist ; p != 0; p = p -> next )
           out << p;
      return out;
 }
```

first of all, you should use a const instead of a non const, second - you needed to assign p to the variable you sent.

hope this helps, have a nice day :)

Comment: I think you mean `&llist`.

Comment: how do i enter a new line here?
-------------------------------------------


no, &llist gives us a pointer to llist, im creating a pointer to 

LList type, so i want p to point to llist.


if i'd do what you say i would have a pointer to an array.


much like having int** i;

int* i2 = i;

Comment: `llist` is a `LList`, not an `LList*`. Doing `&llist` gives you a pointer to an `LList`, which is what `p` is.

Comment: but it recieves a LList ***&*** llist

Comment: That's a reference type. Not a pointer type. Taking the address of it gives you a pointer to `LList`.